# Print only table data in Lightning Web Component(lwc)

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lwc-dom

When I click on the button I need to print the only table data.

Ex:

```
this.template.querySelector('.tablecls');
```

I tried the below options

**Option 1**

```
window.print();
```

The above option is printing the whole window, to overcome this issue I used **slds-no-print** SLDS class.
but I used the Lightning Web Component in Lightning App Page when I click the print button it printing whole window with other components.

**Option 2**

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" class="iframeCls" lwc:dom="manual"></iframe>

// In JS code
window.frames['iframeCls'].document.body.innerHTML = this.template.querySelector('.tablecls').innerHTML;
window.frames['iframeCls'].print();
```

above option not working, it throwing **cannot read property 'document' of undefined**.

any other options to overcome this issue.