# Print Datatable data LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable, datatables.js, printable

I have a data table in LWC component. I want to print the data of that data table. how can I implement this? I've tried `window.print();` but this prints the whole window. anyone knows how can I implement this?

Comment: Where is your component located, what else do you see in print preview? In past I noticed due to locker service it wasn't possible to [print a specific section in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301632/print-only-table-data-in-lightning-web-componentlwc). There is an [open idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpzYUAR/ability-to-print-a-lightning-component) where people posted various workarounds.

Comment: for this, I have created the VF page with all the necessary data, and now I'm able to print specific sections of the Component in PDF format.